# How can I make my class more robust to operator/function overloading?

Tags: python, numpy, operator-overloading, numpy-ufunc

I am writing a class for which objects are initialised with two parameters (`a`, `b`). The intention is to assign instances of this class to variables so that I can have an equation written symbolically in Python code, but have operator overloading perform unique operations on `a` and `b`.

```
import numpy as np


class my_class(object):

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.value1 = a
        self.value2 = b

    # Example of an overloaded operator that works just fine
    def __mul__(self, other):
        new_a = self.value1 * other
        new_b = self.value2 * np.absolute(other)
        return my_class(new_a, new_b)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_object = my_class(100, 1)

    print(np.exp(my_object))    # This doesn't work!
```

In running the above example code, I encountered the following output:

```
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type my_class which has no callable exp method
```

Through guesswork, I was able to see that a complaint about `no callable exp method` probably meant I needed to define a new method in my class:

```
def exp(self):
    new_val1 = np.exp(self.value1)
    new_val2 = np.absolute(new_val1) * self.value2
    return my_class(new_val1, new_val2)
```

which ended up working just fine. But now I will have to write another method for `np.expm1()` and so on as I require. Thankfully I only need `np.exp()` and `np.log()` to work, but I also tried `math.exp()` on my object and I started getting a type error.

So now my question is:
The custom `exp` method in the class seemed to work for *overloading* the NumPy function, but how am I supposed to handle `math.exp()` not working? It must be possible because somehow when calling `math.exp()` on a NumPy array, NumPy understands that a 1-element array can be turned into a scalar and then passed to `math.exp()` without issue.
I mean I guess this technically is about overloading a function, but before I realised defining a new `exp` was the fix to my first problem, I had no idea why a method like `__rpow__` wasn't being called.

Comment: What's the definition of your custom `exp` function?

Comment: In python, `overloading` applies mainly to methods that might be inherited, and the methods that implement the operators.  Methods belong to the object.  Functions choose "for themselves" what kinds of arguments they work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.exp(my_object)` is implemented as `np.exp(np.array(my_object))`.

`np.array(my_object)` is a object dtype array.  `np.exp` tries `elmt.exp()` for each element of the array.  That doesn't work for most classes, since they don't implement such a method.

Same applies for operators and other `ufunc`.

`math.exp` is an unrelated implementation.  It apparently works for something that gives a single numeric value, but I haven't explored that much.  `numpy` will raise an error if it can't do that.

Implementing `*` with a class `__mul__` is done by interpreter.

---

Same error message when using array in `math.exp` and with `__float__()`

```
In [52]: math.exp(np.array([1,2,3]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-52-40503a52084a>", line 1, in <module>
    math.exp(np.array([1,2,3]))
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

In [53]: np.array([1,2,3]).__float__()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-53-0bacdf9df4e7>", line 1, in <module>
    np.array([1,2,3]).__float__()
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Similarly when an array is used in a boolean context (e.g `if`), we can get an error generated with

```
In [55]: np.array([1,2,3]).__bool__()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-55-04aca1612817>", line 1, in <module>
    np.array([1,2,3]).__bool__()
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Similarly using a `sympy` Relational in an `if` results in the error produced by

```
In [110]: (x>0).__bool__()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-110-d88b76ce6b22> in <module>
----> 1 (x>0).__bool__()

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sympy/core/relational.py in __bool__(self)
    396 
    397     def __bool__(self):
--> 398         raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
    399 
    400     def _eval_as_set(self):

TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

`pandas` Series produce a similar error.

Comment: Do you know here the `elmt.exp()` fallback for object arrays is documented?  I can find issues and PRs related to this, e.g., https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/12700, but nothing in the docs.

Comment: No documentation that I know of.  It's just something I've observed from other people's errors.  It has come up, for example, when people try to use `sympy` variables in `numpy` arrays and functions.  Math on object dtype arrays is hit-or-miss, depending on whether this method delegation does something useful or not.

Answer (score 0):

First, on why `math.exp` works with 1-element Numpy arrays: the `numpy.ndarray` class [has a `__float__` method](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#special-methods); this method is part of the Python [data model](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/datamodel.html#object.__float__) for numeric types, and is used when `float(x)` is called.  I couldn't spot anything in the [`math` docs](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/math.html#module-math) that says that `math.exp` casts its argument to `float`, but it's not unreasonable behaviour.

As for customizing behaviour of Numpy's ufuncs: the recommended way to implement "array-like" objects that override ufunc behaviour is [somewhat complicated](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.dispatch.html#basics-dispatch).  I couldn't find documentation on providing `exp`, `log`, etc. methods to customize ufuncs.  Supplying methods like this doesn't work in all cases, for example `np.heaviside`; this example

```py
import numpy as np


class foo:
    
    def exp(self):
        return foo()

    def heaviside(self, other):
        return foo()


print(f'{np.exp(foo()) = }')
print(f'{np.heaviside(foo(), foo()) = }')
```

gives this output:

```
np.exp(foo()) = <__main__.foo object at 0x7efcdbba1ac0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rory/hack/stackoverflow/q70312146/heaviside.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(f'{np.heaviside(foo(), foo()) = }')
TypeError: ufunc 'heaviside' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```