# Use numpy functions on objects extending numbers.Real

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, types, numpy-ufunc

[PEP 3141](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3141/) introduces abstract base classes for different kinds of numbers to allow custom implementations.
I want to derive a class from `numbers.Real` and calculate its sine value. Using pythons `math`-module, this works fine. When I try the same in numpy, I get an error.

```py
from numbers import Real
import numpy as np
import math

class Mynum(Real):
    def __float__(self):
        return 0.0
    # Many other definitions

a = Mynum()

print("math:")
print(math.sin(a))
print("numpy:")
print(np.sin(a))
```

results in

> ```
> math:
> 0.0
> numpy:
> AttributeError: 'Mynum' object has no attribute 'sin'
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> [...]
> in <module>
>     print(np.sin(a)) TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Mynum which has no callable sin method
> ```

It seems like numpy tries to call a `sin`-method of its argument. To me, this is quite confusing since the standard data types (like `float`) do not have such a method either, but `np.sin` works on them.

Is there just some kind of hardcoded check for standard data types, and PEP 3141 is not supported? Or did I miss something in my class?

Because it is quite tedious to implement all required methods, here is my current code that works with the `math`-module:

```
from numbers import Real
import numpy as np
import math

class Mynum(Real):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __abs__(self):
        pass

    def __add__(self):
        pass

    def __ceil__(self):
        pass

    def __eq__(self):
        pass

    def __float__(self):
        return 0.0

    def __floor__(self):
        pass

    def __floordiv__(self):
        pass

    def __le__(self):
        pass

    def __lt__(self):
        pass

    def __mod__(self):
        pass

    def __mul__(self):
        pass

    def __neg__(self):
        pass

    def __pos__(self):
        pass

    def __pow__(self):
        pass

    def __radd__(self):
        pass

    def __rfloordiv__(self):
        pass

    def __rmod__(self):
        pass

    def __rmul__(self):
        pass

    def __round__(self):
        pass

    def __rpow__(self):
        pass

    def __rtruediv__(self):
        pass

    def __truediv__(self):
        pass

    def __trunc__(self):
        pass

a = Mynum()
print("math:")
print(math.sin(a))
print("numpy:")
print(np.sin(a))
```

Comment: That PEP doesn't apply to `numoy's` dtypes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just answered something like this, but I'll repeat myself

```
np.sin(a)
```

is actually

```
np.sin(np.array(a))
```

What does `np.array(a)` produce?  What's its `dtype`?

If it's an object dtype array, that explains that error.  With object dtype array, `numpy` iterates through (the references), and tries to run an appropriate method on each.  That's generally ok with operators which can use `__add__` like methods, but almost no one defines a `sin` or `exp` method.

From yesterday

[How can I make my class more robust to operator/function overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70312146/how-can-i-make-my-class-more-robust-to-operator-function-overloading)

Comparing a numeric dtype array with an object dtype:

```
In [428]: np.sin(np.array([1,2,3]))
Out[428]: array([0.84147098, 0.90929743, 0.14112001])

In [429]: np.sin(np.array([1,2,3], object))
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'sin'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-429-d6927b9a87c7>", line 1, in <module>
    np.sin(np.array([1,2,3], object))
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type int which has no callable sin method
```

Comment: The referenced question was really helpful, especially the following doc entry describing how to create a custom array type: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.dispatch.html#basics-dispatch.

See my own answer below for more detail on what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

See hpaulj’s answer (and the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70312146/how-can-i-make-my-class-more-robust-to-operator-function-overloading)) for the explanation why this did not work.

After reading the documentation, I chose to create a [custom numpy array container](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.dispatch.html#basics-dispatch) and add my own numpy `ufunc` support. The relevant method is

```py
def __array_ufunc__(self, ufunc, method, *args, **kwargs):
    if method == "__call__":
        scalars = []
        for arg in args:
            # CAUTION: order matters here because Mynum is also a number
            if isinstance(arg, self.__class__):
                scalars.append(arg.value)
            elif isinstance(arg, Number):
                scalars.append(arg)
            else:
                return NotImplemented
        return self.__class__(ufunc(*scalars, **kwargs))
    return NotImplemented
```

I chose to support only my own datatype and `numbers.Number` for the ufuncs, which made the implementation quite simple.
See the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.dispatch.html#basics-dispatch) for more detail.

In order to extend `numbers.Real`, we also need to define various magic methods (see [PEP 3141](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3141/)).
By extending [`np.lib.mixins.NDArrayOperatorsMixin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.mixins.NDArrayOperatorsMixin.html#numpy.lib.mixins.NDArrayOperatorsMixin) (in addition to `numbers.Real`), we get most of those for free.
The remaining ones need to be implemented manually.

Below you can see my complete code, which works for `math`-module functions as well as numpys.

```py
from numbers import Real, Number
import numpy as np
import math


class Mynum(np.lib.mixins.NDArrayOperatorsMixin, Real):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}(value={self.value})"

    def __array__(self, dtype=None):
        return np.array(self.value, dtype=dtype)

    def __array_ufunc__(self, ufunc, method, *args, **kwargs):
        if method == "__call__":
            scalars = []
            for arg in args:
                # CAUTION: order matters here because Mynum is also a number
                if isinstance(arg, self.__class__):
                    scalars.append(arg.value)
                elif isinstance(arg, Number):
                    scalars.append(arg)
                else:
                    return NotImplemented
            return self.__class__(ufunc(*scalars, **kwargs))
        return NotImplemented

    # Below methods are needed because we are extending numbers.Real
    # NDArrayOperatorsMixin takes care of the remaining magic functions

    def __float__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.value.__float__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __ceil__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.value.__ceil__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __floor__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.value.__floor__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __round__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.value.__round__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __trunc__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.value.__trunc__(*args, **kwargs)


a = Mynum(0)

print("math:")
print(math.sin(a))
print("numpy:")
print(np.sin(a))
```